# with "for" or / and without "for"

Tags: grammar

> A. We have been friends **for** 10 years now.
>
> B. We have been friends **[ ]** 10 years now.

Is **B** a new trend in contemporary English? Or is it restricted only to colloquial English?
In short, I would like to know when precisely **B** is used and, most importantly, what language registers it is used in.

Comment: Imho, B is only colloquial. And sounds wrong, at that.

Comment: It sounds fine to me, although I don't know if I'd use it in the most formal registers. Could this be another AmE/BrE distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the anniversary of your friendship is coming up soon (in which case, you might even include the date on which you've been friends for ten years), I'd recommend taking the word *now* out of the sentence.

> "We have been friends for ten years."

In informal conversations, the following would likely be just fine. Let's assume someone has asked you, "How long have you and Jed been friends?"

> "We've been friends for, oh, I'd say ten years."

Or,

> "We've been friends for, oh--I'd say about ten years."

Or,

> "Oh, we've been friends for ten years."

By the way, I'm not much of a grammarian, so I'm not sure how you are using the expression "language register."

Comment: @PatrickCălinescu: That's fine with me. Don